# MongoDB Updating Boolean Inside Object

Tags: database, mongodb, discord.js

I am trying to update a boolean inside of an object in my discord.js v13 bot but it does not update here are the things i've tried:

```
                    await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                        logging.enabled: true
                    })
```

```
                    await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                        logging.enabled = true
                    })
```

But none of these seem to update it here is a screenshot of the [db](https://prnt.sc/2UdO2GzMfMad)

I also tried:

```
                    await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                        logging: {"enabled": true}
                    })
```

And that updates it but also erases everything else

Comment: await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate({<here put criteria>},{$set:{"logging.enabled": true})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your error is passing the **update** statement to the **filter** parameter. 
> Your query will find the first doc with { 'logging.enabled' : true }. 
> And don't update anything

```
const filter = { 'logging.enabled' : false};

const update = { 'logging.enabled' : true };

// `doc` is the document _before_ `update` was applied
let doc = await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
// doc.logging.enabled is false


// `doc` is the document _after_ `update` was applied because of
// `new: true`
let doc = await guildSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true
});
// doc.logging.enabled is true
```